# barley content in whisky from barley grains

Tags: mash, wort, whiskey, barley

Of the whiskey in a barrel, what % of it is barley?

From what I understand, to make wort only 20% of spent grain is left.  This leads to a figure of 80% of the grain dissolved in the wort.

After the yeast is added, the wort is distilled, separating the alcohols and leaving stuff behind.  Seemingly the barley that has dissolved in the wort, does not get distilled and gets left behind?

What is the original ratio of water liters to kg of grain?
After distillation, what % of the mixture is distilled off, and what % is left behind?
What would the barley grain makeup of the whiskey mixture be, or just alcohol is distilled taking the converted barley sugars, but leaving all the "barley juice" behind?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but barley does not "dissolve" in wort.

Comment: I don't know the answer either, but the type of whisky matters as to barley content. For example, bourbon must be made from at least 51% corn (maize). Furthermore, this is sort of a philosophical question. The whiskey starts as barley, water and yeast, and anything after that is a byproduct of those products. I will also note that [you asked a similar question in February](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9443/when-making-whiskey-or-beer-what-is-left-of-the-barley?rq=1), and you may wish to refer to it for info on the whisky-making process.

Comment: if barley does not dissolve in wort where does the grain mass go?  The grains go in, and waste comes out.  So what happens to the grain that is not waste?

Comment: @Chino - if I asked a similar but different question, how can I find an answer to a different question?  I clearly asked for specific ratios.  Why is a ratio of liters to grain philosophical?  If you want to be pedantic and include bourbon, why cant you then give some figures rather than just complain about a question?

Comment: Sorry, not meaning to complain. I thought that some of your questions were answered in the info provided previously. I will take a stab at it. I think the answer is philosophical because it is like asking what percent of your body mass is composed of the eggs you have eaten - there is a transformational process that goes on, and it requires some subjective judgment to decide what remains part of the barley as opposed to something that is created by and is part of the enzymes or the yeast.

Comment: To take a stab at the question, you can take an assumed original gravity of wort (1.050, or 4.75% by weight of barley sugar seems like a reasonable estimate after some google fu), go to the White Labs site and find its scotch whiskey yeast and its apparent attenuation rate (75-80%). Calculate how much of the sugar will remain unconverted to alcohol (about 25%) and get its weight, and then figure out how much alcohol will be producted by the yeast from the other 75% of sugars (convert alcohol by weight to alchol by volume). Then it seems that this liquor is distilled to 75% ABV. (continued...)

Comment: ... (continued) [Source](http://homedistiller.org/grain/wash-grain). So you will need to make some assumptions as to how much barley sugar remains in the distillate (probably very little), and do some math. Then the distillate is diluted with water to 63.4%, so do some more math. This assumes you are making 100% barley scotch whiskey, and that none of the grains other than the sugar makes it into the final product, and as well that all yeast and bacteria contribute nothing, and that the products of the mash enzymes and the yeast/bacteria metabolism (mainly alcohol) remain "barley".

Comment: This is pretty good stuff. Thanks.  But would be better as an answer than in comments?

Comment: Part of the starch from the grains will be converted to sugar, but this isn't the grain dissolving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [ProBrewer page](http://www.probrewer.com/resources/distilling/whiskey.php) about whiskey distillation, the initial mash is 100Kg of malted barley and 600 litres of water, for a 6:1 ratio. This yields 80 - 87 litres of 80 proof spirit.

As for the waste, U.S. [2-row malt](http://www.beersmith.com/Grains/Grains/grain_59.htm) has an extract potential of 79%, so 21% of the malt (modulo conversion efficiency), by weight, is *not* converted to sugar. That would be 21 Kg of spend grain in our theoretical batch. The malt will absorb some water (around 1 l/Kg according to [BYO](http://byo.com/brown-ale/item/410-calculating-water-usage-advanced-brewing)), so the total weight of the spent grain will around 121 Kg.

Answer (score 1):

To sort of answer part of your question, in making scotch whiskey for example, the wort is fermented into a "Wash", which is double-distilled into a "new make spirit" containing 60-70% abv., which is then diluted with water to approximately 63.5% abv before being put into barrels for aging. Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_malt_whisky).